# Object has no method setStore() - Sencha Touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Having a slight problem whilst trying to implement local storage into a Sencha Touch 2 app. I have it finding the data from my external store, but after that the function in my controller is supposed to switch the views store to the local storage store I have created once it finds and stores data initially.

I have a reference to the view I want to update the store of, but when I try to update it using setStore it gives me the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'setStore'

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is the code:

Controller:
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

```
config: {
    refs: {
        buyTicketsView: 'buyticketspanel'
    },
    control: {
        'buyticketspanel list': {
            itemsingletap: 'buytickets'
        },
        buyTicketsView : {
            show: 'loadTickets'
        }
    }
},

buytickets: function(list, idx, el, record) {
    Ext.Msg.confirm('External Link', 'Open external link?', function(result){
        if (result == 'yes') {
            //window.location = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + record.get('id');
            window.location = 'http://' + record.get('link');
        }
    });
},

loadTickets: function() {
    //set up refs to the two stores
    var ticketStore = Ext.getStore('ticketStore');
    var ticketStoreLocalStorage= Ext.getStore('buyTicketsLocalStorage');

    //load the localStorage store
    ticketStoreLocalStorage.load();

    // check if localStorage contains data
    if ((ticketStoreLocalStorage.getCount()) == 0) {
        // nothing found so  we need to load the data from external source
        console.log('localStorage data not found');
        //hand off to onMarkerStoreLoad function (below)
        ticketStore.on({
            load: 'onTicketStoreLoad',
            scope: this
        });
        //call load to trigger above
        ticketStore.load();
    } else {
        // we are ok, just print some debug
        console.log('localStorage data found');
        console.log('localStorage count:' + ticketStoreLocalStorage.getCount());
    }
    //finally set the list's store to localStorage
    console.log(this.getBuyTicketsView());
    //THIS LINE IS THE ONE THAT IS FAILING
    this.getBuyTicketsView().setStore(ticketStoreLocalStorage);

},
onTicketStoreLoad: function() {
    //set up refs
    var ticketStoreLocalStorage= Ext.getStore('buyTicketsLocalStorage');
    var ticketStore = Ext.getStore('ticketStore');
        //loop through each data item and add to localStorage
    ticketStore.each(function(item){
        ticketStoreLocalStorage.add(item);
    });
    ticketStoreLocalStorage.sync();
 }
```

View:

```
extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
xtype: 'buyticketspanel',

config: {
    navigationBar: {
       hidden: true
    },
    title: 'Buy Tickets',
    iconCls: 'MyScheduleIcon nav-schedule',
    items: [
        {
            docked: 'top',
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            title: '<span class="logo"></span>'
        },
        {
          xtype: 'list',

          itemTpl: '<div class="date-circle">{date}</div><div class="event-title">{title} - {location}</div><div class="buy-tickets-btn">Buy Tickets</div>'
       }
    ]

}
```

Edit: It also isn't showing the data on the view after switching to the localstorage store for it's data, which makes me think that it isn't actually switching.

Comment: Yup and set you as the right answer. Thanks for the help! I used your second solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`buyticketspanel` is a navigation view because that extends `Ext.navigation.View` and navigation doesn't have `setStore` method, That error is saying exactly the same thing.

Be clear, you are trying to set store to the list, not to the navigation view.

This what you done in controller

```
this.getBuyTicketsView().setStore(ticketStoreLocalStorage);
```

`this.getBuyTicketsView()` - is gives you navigation view, not the list.

You can solve this in many ways.

**Solution 1**

```
this.getBuyTicketsView().down('list').setStore(ticketStoreLocalStorage);
```

**Solution 2**

Give itemId to your list.

```
{
  xtype: 'list',
  itemId : 'buytick',  
  itemTpl: ['<div class="date-circle">{date}</div>'+
            '<div class="event-title">{title} - {location}</div>'+
            '<div class="buy-tickets-btn">Buy Tickets</div>'].join()
}
```

Do this in controller

```
this.getBuyTicketsView().getComponent('buytick').setStore(ticketStoreLocalStorage);
```

**Note**

I given `buytick` as itemId to the list, so i passed `buytick` in  `getComponent()`

**Reference**

[navigation](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.navigation.View)

[list setStore](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List-method-setStore)

[getComponent](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Container-method-getComponent)

Comment: Hi there,
Thanks for the help. I'm not receiving an error which is good but it doesn't appear to be outputting any data from my switched store to my view. Any idea why this might be?

Comment: @MrFirthy first you need to check store has data or not.

Comment: @MrFirthy before setting the store for getBuyTicketsView, console.log(ticketStoreLocalStorage) and check for data

Comment: Will it not set the store if there is no data in it then? My function initially checks if there is no data and if there isn't then passes it off to the onTicketStoreLoad function to populate the localstorage store with data from the external store. Do you think this flow needs to be re-arranged so that the transfer to the new store is only done when there is data in the new one?

Comment: @MrFirthy in loadTickets function, the flow is going to if block or else

Comment: Well after the initial storing of data to localstorage, it shows that there is data in the store and successfully sets the store for the view. However it still isn't displaying anything.

Comment: @MrFirthy set height for the list